# jQuery check last operation of each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `divs` with same class name. I made an `jQuery` `each()` call. I need to check last operation of this `each()` loop(when in `Operation 4` text div executes). Here is the code -

```js
jQuery('.selected-div').each(function () {});
```

```html
<div id="Message area">
  <div class="selected-div">
    Operation 1
  </div>
  <div class="selected-div">
    Operation 2
  </div>
  <div class="selected-div">
    Operation 3
  </div>
  <div class="selected-div">
    Operation 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "check last operation" ? I'm sorry but this doesn't seem clear.

Comment: Use the first param of `each` which is _index_. `if(index === 3) { last element }`.

Comment: "check last operation" means last execution of an each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something *different* on the last execution of the loop, you have at least a couple of choices:

1. Save the jQuery object to a variable and then, in the `each` loop, check the index of the current iteration against `.length - 1`:

   ```
   var divs = jQuery('.selected-div');
   divs.each(function(index) {
       if (index === divs.length - 1) {
           // Last iteration
       } else {
           // Not last
       }
   });
   ```
2. Move the last operation into a separate function:

   ```
   jQuery('.selected-div').slice(0, -1).each(function() {
      // Not the last
   }).end().last().each(function() {
      // Last
   });
   ```

   There, we use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice) to get all but the last element, then `each` to loop through them, then [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end) to get back the full set of elements, then [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last) to get just the last one, and `each` to call a function, passing it in.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
var lastEle = $('.selected-div').last().get(0);
$('.selected-div').each(function (index, element) {
  if (element === lastEle) {
    do your action
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a place holder for the last element.

JavaScript

```
var placeHolder;
$('.selected-div').each(function () {
  // your code
  // append $(this) to placeHolder
  placeHolder = $(this);
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/robbroden/m9fgmqfk/)